# ASP.net web.config error "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level"

Tags: iis, web-config

This question has been asked before, but I have followed all the steps listed in the answers given and still get the same error.

I have IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003. I created a subfolder in the wwwroot folder, containing my web.config file, .cs files, html files and aspx files.
I used IIS Manager to set up the subfolder as an application.
Everything was working fine 2 months ago. Since then, I have been busy with other projects, and didn't have time to complete this.

I have now gone back to complete the project, but I get the error (referencing the  line in the web.config file:
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.

To confirm:
1. There are no sub-folders in this particular folder that have a web.config file. There is no web.config file in the parent folder either.
2. The sub-folder is listed as an application (IIS > Web Sites > (my site) > Properties > Home Directory > Application Settings)

All of my files were coded in a text editor, and were working until recently...

Are there any other possible issues?

If it helps, the same IP address currently hosts another site, which is in its own sub-folder under wwwroot. This second site has its own web.config file and works with no problems.

If it helps, here is my web.config file contents (comments removed):

```
<configuration>

<appSettings>
    <add key="UserMustChangePasswordAtNextLogon" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnlockAccountWhenResettingPassword" value="true"/>
    <add key="DefaultPassword" value=""/>
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings/>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" urlLinePragmas="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false"  type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>

    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>



<system.codedom>
</system.codedom>

<system.webServer>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your web.config content and simply deleted the deny users tag. The web.config works for me.

Try creating another Application and host it in IIS. See if that works. If it does, copy all the files from the existing folder to the new Application folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are precompiling your views, you might get this problem. Clean your solution to clear the issue (you may even need to brute force delete the bin and obj folders).

Of course, you build your solution AFTER you clean it. :)

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean, since I've never compiled or built a web app (I thought they compile at run-time...), but I don't think anything is precompiled since removing the windows authentication line gives a different error (Denied Access since I don't allow anonymous logon). Where would these bin and obj folders be?

Comment: ah. my answer is probably not applicable. I made the assumption you were using visual studio to build and possibly deploy the webapp (at least locally)

Comment: yeah...i didn't bother with any of that...just uploaded my files to the server (and they worked initially :P). Thanks for trying tho.